# Display error input within the else blocks if scanner.nextInt() is invalid

Tags: java

I know there is a lot of code, but focus mainly within the empty else spaces in the blocks after speed is defined for the scanner. I would like the else's to print loops of code if the user does not enter in an integer, saying "Try again! Invalid input." etc; however I have no clue where to go with it. I have heard of "catch" and "exception," but could someone possibly explain it to me or post an updated block of code for me with an explanation. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class M2A1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Birthday;
        int Bday = 2;
        int speed;
        int penalty;
        System.out.println("You were pulled by a police officer believing you were speeding in a 55mph zone.");
        System.out.println("You hand over your license and registration. Is it possibly your birthday today?");
        System.out.println("Use yes(y) or no(n) to answer the above!");
        Birthday = input.nextLine();
        if (Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Great, your bad driving may have happened on a good day.");
            Bday = 1;
        }
        else if (Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            System.out.println("That's ok. Maybe you drove under the speed limit.");
            Bday = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            while (!(Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))) {
                System.out.println("Invalid response. Try again!");
                System.out.println("Use yes(y) or no(n) to answer the above!");
                Birthday = input.nextLine();
                if (Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Great, your bad driving may have happened on a good day.");
                }
                else if (Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || Birthday.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                {
                    System.out.println("That's ok.");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("How fast were you going?");
        speed = input.nextInt();

        if (Bday == 1) {
            if (speed <= 65)
            {
                penalty = 0;
                System.out.println("Great job driving, and the officer wishes you a happy birthday! You drove at " +speed+ "mph! You lost " +penalty+ " points from your license.");
            }
            else if (speed > 65 && speed <= 85)
            {
                penalty = 1;
                System.out.println("You are driving a little fast, but the officer wishes you a happy birthday! You drove at " +speed+ "mph! You lost " +penalty+ " points from your license.");
            }
            else if (speed > 85)
            {
                penalty = 2;
                System.out.println("You are driving way too fast, even for your birthday. You drove at " +speed+ "mph! You lost " +penalty+ " points from your license.");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        if (Bday == 0) {
            if (speed <= 60)
            {
                penalty = 0;
                System.out.println("Great job driving! You drove at " +speed+ "mph! You lost " +penalty+ " points from your license.");
            }
            else if (speed > 60 && speed <= 80)
            {
                penalty = 1;
                System.out.println("You are driving a little fast! You drove at " +speed+ "mph! You lost " +penalty+ " points from your license.");
            }
            else if (speed > 80)
            {
                penalty = 2;
                System.out.println("You are driving WAY too fast! You drove at " +speed+ "mph! You lost " +penalty+ " points from your license.");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner actually has a hasNextInt() method which might be what you are looking for.

An example of using this method in your example could look something like:

```
while(!input.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println("Try again! Invalid Input");
    input.nextLine(); //This clears the buffer and will allow the user to enter again.
}
speed = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: I had no idea of this method before, and thanks for the help, however if I enter in a character like p, it doesn't explain the code above and causes the program to end itself. Is there any possible reason why it wouldn't work?